# ¿Cómo ocultar la opción Exportar productos en Odoo 13?

Tags: odoo

Deseo ocultar la opción Exportar del modulo Ventas y el icono para export all, sección Cotizaciones, gracias.

[image: Odoo]

Answer (score 1):

He trabajado sobre la versión 10 y pude ocultar el botón de importar de la siguiente manera:

```
odoo.define('cc_v1.refresh_view', function (require) {
    "use strict";

    var core = require("web.core");
    var utils = require('web.utils');
    var Sidebar = require("web.Sidebar");
    var _t = core._t;

    Sidebar.include({
        add_items: function(section_code, items) {
            var self = this;
            var _super = this._super;
            var export_label = _t("Export");
            var new_items = items;
            if (section_code === "other") {
                new_items = [];
                for (var i = 0; i < items.length; i++) {
                    console.log("items[i]: ", items[i]);
                    if (items[i]["label"] !== export_label) {
                        new_items.push(items[i]);
                    }
                }
            }
            if (new_items.length > 0) {
                _super.call(self, section_code, new_items);
            } else {
                _super.call(self, section_code, items);
            }
        }
    });
});
```

Lo que añadi fue un fichero javascript llamando a Sidebar. Luego le añadí en el manifest. Espero te pueda ayudar este código, no lo he intentado en la versión 13, pero debe ser muy parecido.
Si deseas ocultar solo para el modulo de ventas, puedes utilizar un grupo para chequear si pertenecen o no.